Blender: How to change the viewport color for a line or curve
Viewport colors seem to apply only to faces and, hence, not to 2D curves. Is there a way to change the color of 2D curves (bezier, mesh, NURBS) in the viewport?
My application requires extensive 2D manipulation before applying 3D properties.

